# Selecting the next item in LongListSelector windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, selecteditem, longlistselector

I have an app where a LongListSelector displayes a list of pictures from a web service, when the user then clicks the picture a large image viewer pops up and shows it.

What I would like to implement is a next key where when pressed the next item in the LongListSelector is selected.

If I was using a ListBox, I would simply use the flowing code

```
ListBox.SelectedIndex = ListBox.SelectedIndex + 1;
```

I would then handle the code in the SelectionChanged event.
But LongListSelector does not have a `.SelectedIndex` only a `.SelectedItem`

Is there a similar way of doing this with a LongListSelector.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `SelectedItem`, find out its index in your collection and then assign the item with index+1 in your collection to the `SelectedItem`.

Comment: I can get the selected index using the following `selector.ItemsSource.IndexOf(selector.SelectedItem as TranslatedItem2);` but how do I assign the index + 1 to the `SelectedItem` ?

Comment: selector.SelectedItem  = selector.ItemsSource[index+1]

Comment: Thank you, my only problem is I cannot apply indexing [] to an IEnumerable.

Comment: I ended up using this `GridView.ItemsSource.Cast<TranslatedItem2>().ElementAt(currentpic + 1);`at that works great, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.